# Downloaded video not showing in my android 10 gallery

Tags: android

From my app downloaded videos are saved in below created path but not showing in gallery for android 10 but I have checked in android N it is showing in gallery. sorry for my bad english!

Here is below created path ,

```
File mydownload = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/SavedVideos");

            if (!mydownload.exists()) {
                mydownload.mkdir();
            }
```

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory ()` is deprecated - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

. If you want to continue using it, you can add the following in your manifest `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Comment: `mydownload.mkdir();` The directory is not even created but you dont know as you do not check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, need to do scan media files using broadcast intent.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(YOUR_PATH)));
```